# getting this error: XFC0002 EventHandler "AddRecordButton_Clicked" with correct signature not found in type "CarMaintenanceApp.MainPage"

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.android, event-handling

we are trying to make a car maintenance tracking app, however this one error wont go away.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   XFC0002 EventHandler "AddRecordButton_Clicked" with correct signature not found in type "CarMaintenanceApp.MainPage".   CarMaintenanceApp   K:\Android1\App1\App1\App\CarMaintenanceApp\CarMaintenanceApp\MainPage.xaml 26
```

this is the mainpage.xaml file

```
<!-- MainPage.xaml -->
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="CarMaintenanceApp.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <!-- Add other UI elements as needed -->

            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MaintenanceRecords}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Description}" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Date}" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

            <Button Text="Add Record" Clicked="AddRecordButton_Clicked" />


            <Picker Title="Maintenance Type" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMaintenanceType}">
                <Picker.Items>
                    <x:String>Oil Change</x:String>
                    <x:String>Tire Rotation</x:String>
                    <!-- يمكنك إضافة نوع صيانة إضافي هنا -->
                </Picker.Items>
            </Picker>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

this is the mainpage.xaml.cs file, i would love to know if there is anything wrong with this code that cold be causing this error

```
using CarMaintenanceApp;
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    MainViewModel1 viewModel;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        viewModel = new MainViewModel1();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    // Remove the auto-generated method as it's not needed and causing an error
    // private void InitializeComponent()
    // {
    //     throw new NotImplementedException();
    // }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        var oilChangeRecord = new MaintenanceRecord
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now,
            Description = "Oil Change",
            Type = MaintenanceType.OilChange
        };

        var tireRotationRecord = new MaintenanceRecord
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now,
            Description = "Tire Rotation",
            Type = MaintenanceType.TireRotation
        };

        viewModel.AddMaintenanceRecord(oilChangeRecord);
        viewModel.AddMaintenanceRecord(tireRotationRecord);
    }

    private void AddRecordButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedMaintenanceType = viewModel.SelectedMaintenanceType;

        var record = new MaintenanceRecord
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now,
            Description = "Maintenance Description",
            Type = selectedMaintenanceType
            // يمكنك تحديد الخصائص الأخرى حسب الحاجة
        };

        viewModel.AddMaintenanceRecord(record);

        // إعادة تعيين SelectedMaintenanceType إذا كان ذلك ضروريًا
        // viewModel.SelectedMaintenanceType = null;
    }
}
```

as we do not understand this too much we havent tried many things. we're open to all ideas

Comment: The XAML creates a class `MainPage` in namespace `CarMaintenanceApp` while your cs file puts the class in the global namespace. There is a `namespace CarMaintenanceApp {...}` missing around the class.

Comment: where exactly do i put it

Comment: Between the usings and the class declaration. If you are using the curly- braces syntax then of course you need to enclose the whole class code.